# Can I use 'please' in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I wanted to send an email to politely remind the recipient (a client) of some work that I'd done which they needed to to review. This was the top email, while the rest of the body of the work was in the attachments/body.

> Hi Recipient,
>
> Just wondering if you've had a chance to review this please?
>
> Kind regards,
>
> xxxx

The 'please' was added to make the request a bit more subtle as this is the second follow up, however the more I look at it the more wrong it seems. Is there a better way to phrase this please?

Comment: As a native English speaker person I find it hilarious that this was migrated here.

Answer (score 4):

As "please" is generally associated with requests and your sentence is most certainly not a question, you indeed cannot use please in this context.

I believe that

> Just wondering if you've had a chance to review this.

would have sufficed. If you're looking for something more subtle, I've always been a fan of writing something along the lines of

> Hey, I emailed you such-and-such amount of time ago about this issue that you were supposed to respond to me about. I don't seem to have gotten your email though; did something happen?

Comment: +1 I'm a big fan of the "maybe my email was down?" rhetorical gambit.

Answer (score 0):

I am following up on my  prior request. Please advise when I should expect your response.

Kind Regards

There is no need for sweetness in a business correspondence. You have to be clear and formal.

Comment: This seems very cold and distant to me. But thanks

Comment: Although I can't comment on whether "Please advise when" is grammatically appropriate, it's also certainly a rather unnatural AmE construction.

Comment: @SamuelLijin Submissiveness, no, but sweetness, sure.  Diplomacy is always a classy ornament to professional endeavor.  (P.S. Your organization doesn't let you directly communicate with anybody outside who has budgetary discretion, do they? That is to say, Oh just *try* that on a corporate customer and see how it works.)